# What has happened to the Gmail app for Mac OS X?

Tags: mail.app, gmail

I used a mail app on my MacBook Pro for 6+ years that I am convinced was called Gmail. Its icon resembled that of Gmail for iOS. I had lots of mail stored in folders on my local computer. My Mac recently had to have a factory reset to resolve an issue with installing Monterey and so I lost all of my applications. I have a data backup. Now I cannot find the Gmail app or a good functional equivalent in the App store. All seem only to provide access to mail on the Gmail server, in the same way as the web interface. I cannot find one that supports local folders. Am I misremembering or has the Gmail app for Mac OSX disappeared?

Comment: There's never been a Google® official Gmail app for macOS. [This site](https://www.rightinbox.com/blog/gmail-apps-for-mac) may have some leads for you to pursue.

Comment: I‘ve removed the second question, please ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Google has never made a Gmail app for macOS.

---

You can use local folders in Mail.app: https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/mlhlp1021/mac.

> On My Mac: Mailboxes you create in On My Mac are local, meaning you can access them only on the Mac where you created them.